# Ansatz and HJB equation

Tags: stochastic-calculus, itos-lemma, stochastic-control

Suppose we have an HJB equation of the form
$$
\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^{2}\frac{\partial^{2}v}{\partial s^{2}}+max_{\delta^{a}}\left\{ \lambda^{a}(\delta^{a})\left[v(t,s,x+s+\delta^{a},q-1)-v(t,s,x,q)\right]\right\}+max_{\delta^{b}}\left\{ \lambda^{b}(\delta^{b})\left[v(t,s,x-s+\delta^{b},q+1)-v(t,s,x,q)\right]\right\} 
$$
with terminal condition
$$
v(T,s,x,q)=-e^{-\gamma(x+qs)}
$$
We will search a solution of the form
$$
v(t,s,x,q)=-e^{-\gamma\left(x+\theta(t,s,q)\right)}=f(x,\theta(t,s,q))
$$
by direct substitution into HJB equation and application of the chain rule we get
$$
\frac{\partial f(x,\theta(t,s,q))}{\partial\theta(t,s,q)}\frac{\partial\theta(t,s,q)}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^{2}\left[\frac{\partial f(x,\theta(t,s,q))}{\partial\theta(t,s,q)}\frac{\partial^{2}\theta(t,s,q)}{\partial s^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2}f(x,\theta(t,s,q))}{\partial\theta(t,s,q)^{2}}\left(\frac{\partial\theta(t,s,q)}{\partial s}\right)^{2}\right]+max_{\delta^{a}}\left\{ \lambda^{a}(\delta^{a})\left[f(x+s+\delta^{a},\theta(t,s,q-1))-f(x,\theta(t,s,q))\right]\right\} +max_{\delta^{b}}\left\{ \lambda^{b}(\delta^{b})\left[f(x-s+\delta^{b},\theta(t,s,q+1))-f(x,\theta(t,s,q))\right]\right\} 
$$
taking derivatives of $f$
$$
\gamma f(x,\theta(t,s,q))\frac{\partial\theta(t,s,q)}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^{2}\left[\gamma f(x,\theta(t,s,q))\frac{\partial^{2}\theta(t,s,q)}{\partial s^{2}}-\gamma^{2}f(x,\theta(t,s,q))\left(\frac{\partial\theta(t,s,q)}{\partial s}\right)^{2}\right]+max_{\delta^{a}}\left\{ \lambda^{a}(\delta^{a})\left[f(x+s+\delta^{a},\theta(t,s,q-1))-f(x,\theta(t,s,q))\right]\right\}+max_{\delta^{b}}\left\{ \lambda^{b}(\delta^{b})\left[f(x-s+\delta^{b},\theta(t,s,q+1))-f(x,\theta(t,s,q))\right]\right\} 
$$
dividing by $\gamma f(x,\theta(t,s,q))$
$$
\frac{\partial\theta(t,s,q)}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^{2}\left[\frac{\partial^{2}\theta(t,s,q)}{\partial s^{2}}-\gamma\left(\frac{\partial\theta(t,s,q)}{\partial s}\right)^{2}\right]+max_{\delta^{a}}\left\{ \frac{\lambda^{a}(\delta^{a})}{\gamma}\left[e^{-\gamma\left(s+\delta^{a}+\theta(t,s,q-1)-\theta(t,s,q)\right)}-1\right]\right\}+max_{\delta^{b}}\left\{ \frac{\lambda^{b}(\delta^{b})}{\gamma}\left[e^{\gamma\left(s-\delta^{b}-\theta(t,s,q+1)+\theta(t,s,q)\right)}-1\right]\right\} 
$$
Is this correct? It is claimed that with this ansatz we should instead have
$$
\frac{\partial\theta(t,s,q)}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^{2}\left[\frac{\partial^{2}\theta(t,s,q)}{\partial s^{2}}-\gamma\left(\frac{\partial\theta(t,s,q)}{\partial s}\right)^{2}\right]+max_{\delta^{a}}\left\{ \frac{\lambda^{a}(\delta^{a})}{\gamma}\left[1-e^{-\gamma\left(s+\delta^{a}+\theta(t,s,q-1)-\theta(t,s,q)\right)}\right]\right\} +max_{\delta^{b}}\left\{ \frac{\lambda^{b}(\delta^{b})}{\gamma}\left[1-e^{\gamma\left(s-\delta^{b}-\theta(t,s,q+1)+\theta(t,s,q)\right)}\right]\right\} 
$$
Not really sure why signs are different, but think I am missing something really trivial.

Comment: derivatives had a wrong sign (had to be γ(-f) instead of γf for example)

Answer (score 1):

derivatives had a wrong sign (had to be γ(-f) instead of γf for example)